# How do I get width and heigth of picturebox image coming from ImageLocation?

Tags: c#, picturebox

I'm trying to expand my form depending on the resolution of the selected image on the picturebox. But it seems like the picturebox size is not changing when I change the image... any help?

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = reader["imagem"].ToString();
pictureBox1.Height = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
pictureBox1.Width = pictureBox1.Image.Width;
/*mw and mh are the main width and main heigth,
 i used this in case the user selects another 
 image, then the window returns to it's original
 size before changing again.*/
this.Height = mh;
this.Width = mw;
this.Height += pictureBox1.Image.Height;
this.Width = pictureBox1.Image.Width + 16;
if (this.Width < mw)
{
    this.Width = mw;
}
this.CenterToParent();
```

This is only the part of the code which I need a fix. The rest is all right and the picturebox is showing the image I select, but it's not changing sizes.

Comment: Using ImageLocation is fine, but you'll have to set the WaitOnLoad property to True if you want to use the Image property next.  Or better yet, use the LoadCompleted event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I just figured it out guys, I changed

**This part:**

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = reader["imagem"].ToString();
```

**To this:**

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(reader["imagem"].ToString());
```